# When a term has letters as subscripts they looked squished. How can I improve the appearance?

Tags: math-mode, subscripts, anki

When I have a term that has letters as subscripts, the letters look squished and frankly, are hard to read in some cases. Is there some easy tweak I can do that will improve the readability of the scripts? This is an example:

$A_G = {a_{ij}}$

I actually find it difficult to tell the difference between the i and j without looking at it carefully. The letters actually don't look as if they are proportional to their non-subscript counterparts, hence the description 'squished.

EDIT:

I am using latex with Anki. These are the options I have for the note type:

```
\documentclass[10pt,letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Arial}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath,amsfonts,mathrsfs}
\begin{document} 

$A_G = \{a_{ij}\}$ 

\end{document}
```

The 'squished' appearance doesn't happen with numbers that are subscripts. They actually look proportional to their non-subscript counterparts.

Example:

[image]

Comment: Does it happen with the standard fonts, or just with some fonts you happen to be using? It might be handy if you were to provide a minimal working example.

Comment: I added some details about the font and packages installed. I am using Latex with Anki.

Comment: can you provide a visual example?  the code you've shown doesn't allow us to compile with any guarantee that we're getting the same result, because it isn't in a single compilable example.

Comment: How do I render Latex source? I looked through the help documentation but it seems mostly about how to do the basic formatting one does on any one of the StackExchange sites.